# Laravel extending a model

Tags: laravel, class, eloquent

In my model file Category.php I am extending the Category Class...

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;
    public $table = "category";

    public function subcategories(){ 
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategory::class)->orderBy('name');
    }    

}

class ProductCategory extends Category
{
    public $table = 'product_categories';
}
```

But when i try to access the ProductCategory Model It is not available, am i forgetting an import somewhere?

```
$partcategories = PartCategory::orderBy('name')->get();
```

This is the error i get...

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductCategory' not found

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, create a separate class file for the `PartCategory`, if you haven't already.

```
namespace App;

class ProductCategory extends Category
{
    public $table = 'product_categories';
}
```

Secondly, where you are using the model, make sure you are importing the `PartCategory` class correctly:

```
use App\PartCategory;
```

Then you can use the model as you had:

```
$partcategories = PartCategory::orderBy('name')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! moving it to a separate file fixed it!